# Android Brush Texture

Tags: android, graphics, paint, brush

does anyone know how to apply textures to a brush in android, apart from the normal OVAL, CIRCLE and rectange. Any help at all would be appreciated, or any resources where i can read about it.

since stackoverflow isnt letting me post and image of the brush click [here](http://www.layersforiphone.com/) and check the brush section

I want to make something like that, is it done redrawing a .png or is it many `path` s around a given area?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13307282/